# How to make the records of a user in a top level business unit be visible to a lower level business unit user?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

How can User Y see the activities created by User X ? 
[image]

EDIT:

Please note that User X has been added to the same team as User Y but still Y cannot see X's activities, but X can see Y's activities.

This case happened when a sales person in BU 3 left the firm so User X is working in place of that person along with User Y and so user Y needs to see the activities by User X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of the activities has to be changed to the team where both users are added.

After that all members of the team can see the activities. If you assign records to a team, assure that this team has sufficient security rights (at least read).